# Ruby gsub partial match

Tags: ruby, gsub

I have a string like this :

```
string = "Workshop (, ) (, ) (Corporate, October 2017)"
```

I need to change a string to be :

```
"Workshop (Corporate, October 2017)"
```

but I have tried using the following code :

```
string.gsub(/([(),])/, '')
#=> "Workshop Corporate October 2017"
```

Is it possible to change a string like what I mean? I'm new in ruby and still learning.

Comment: Are there specific and exact requirements you can describe, such as "remove all `()` groups containing only a comma `,` and optionally one or more whitespaces?" Is the comma required or optional?

Comment: Your `[(),]` defines a character class that matches any `(`, `)` and `,` in no particular order.

Comment: Where does the string come from? Looks like it was generated incorrectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't use a regexp for this:

```
string = "Workshop (, ) (, ) (Corporate, October 2017)"
string.gsub(' (, )', '')
#=> "Workshop (Corporate, October 2017)"
```